# How to get and modify the name of input type in generic type

Tags: typescript

I have a repetitive task of creating new type in this shape:

```
type SomethingAggregateData = {
    something_aggregate: {
        nodes: Something[];
    }
}
```

Now I want to make a generic which can help me, look like `AggregateData<Something>`

So, I can use it like:

```
type AppleAggregateData = AggregateData<Apple>
// will be valid with
type AppleAggregateData = {
    apple_aggregate: {
        nodes: Apple[];
    }
}
```

I tried to Google but still stuck at getting the input type `Something` name and make it become  the `something_aggregate` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With typescript 4.1+, you could use a template literal type to restrict the key name for the type. You just need to provide the name itself.

```
type AggregateData<T, K extends string> = Record<`${K}_aggregate`, { nodes: T[] }>;

type Apple = { name: string };
type AppleAggregateData = AggregateData<Apple, 'apple'>;
const x: AppleAggregateData = {
    apple_aggregate: {
        nodes: [{ name: 'macintosh' }],
    },
};
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to formulate this with a single generic type parameter, as far as I know, there's no way to get the type name as a string. Hypothetically speaking, if we had that capability we might try to do this:

```
// sadly "NameOf<>" does not exist
type AggregateData2<T> = Record<`${Lowercase<NameOf<T>>}_aggregate`, { nodes: T[] }>;
```

Comment: I think this  is the best we can move on for now. The `Lowercase` is really useful, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If all the inner objects are the same (`something_aggregate`, `apple_aggregate`) but only the nodes type changes you could pass a generic type to `SomethingAggregateData`:

```
type AggregateData<T> = {
  aggregate: {
    nodes: T[]
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
type AppleAggregateData = AggregateData<Apple>
```

now the type `AppleAggregateData` should have nodes with type `Apple[]`

```
 type AppleAggregateData = {
     aggregate: {
         nodes: Apple[]
     }
 }
```

Comment: Sadly I can't change the `something_aggregate` part, it comes from backend.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As Jeff mentioned in newer Typescript you can generate dynamic keys using string literals, and avoid passing full `${resource}_aggregate` as a generic parameter (as in my example)

You can't have dynamic keys defined in your types as you suggested (`something_aggregate`), but you can do something like this:

```
type AggregateData<TAggreationKey extends string | number | symbol, TValue> = {
    [TKey in TAggreationKey]: {
        nodes: TValue[];
    }
}

type AppleAggregateData = AggregateData<'apple_aggregate', Apple>;
```

That would give you type you wanted, but you'd need to write key for `{ nodes: TValue[] }` yourself, it couldn't be calculated.

Here is a [typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAXAngBwQQVaiCC88A3gL4BQpK68GA5jXDVIiACJNQA8AKrfSEwEsA9gDsA0iGTwQAD2YjgAZ3iLEMASJrwAPvBEBXALYAjEDB0rkJoRAA08LgDUoEfSAB88AoVLw-8AG0uCSkNB144QVEQgF0ALiJff2SRIVBFBKcXNwCYgG4kvzIyCjRMbFwIkEZmNkQoL2o6BiZWdg4AcigKkAB9KGbq1o77LBwPAqA) showing this same example.

Comment: Thank you, look like I have to move on with this limitation.